# WPF + UserControl + OnClosing event

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, events

I write an application in WPF where I have one main page and one user control in it. I need to call function when I close the page where user control is embedded. I can't call this function from the main page, I need to do it directly in user control (as I don't have access to main page). There is an event unloaded for user control, but it is called to late. How can I get something like onclosing event?

Comment: Just double checking, your `UserControl` is in a `Page` and not a `Window` right? Just asking becuase you mentioned `OnClosing`

Comment: Yes it is in Page, not a Window

Comment: Kind of hard without some sample code. Is your `Page` in a `Frame` where you are calling `Navigate` or what does it look like?